# Torus and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

Let $0<r<a$ be fixed. For $(\alpha,\beta)\in[0,2\pi]^2$ we consider

$$
g(e^{i\alpha},e^{i\beta}) = ((a+r\cos\alpha)\cos\beta,(a+r\cos\alpha)\sin\beta,r\sin\alpha)
$$

I would like to prove it is an homeomorphism from $S^1 \times S^1$ to $g(S^1 \times S^1)$.

The fact it is onto is clear. The fact the map is continuous is clear since each coordinate function is continuous. The conclusion should follow from the fact that a bijective and continuous map from a compact metric space to another is an homeomorphism.

However I have some difficulty to prove it is injective. I tried to usual machinery by considering $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ and  $(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$ such that $g(e^{i\alpha_1},e^{i\beta_1})=g(e^{i\alpha_2},e^{i\beta_2})$ but I get nothing interesting using the trigonometry formula I know and I wonder if it is the good way to prove the fact it is objective.

I would like to know if there is another way I should look for, more « economical », to prove that the map is injective please. Thank you a lot

Comment: Thinking geometrically should help. The image of $g$ is the torus obtained by rotating the circle $(x-a)^2+z^2=r^2,\ y=0$ (corresponding to $\beta=0$) around $z$-axis. $\alpha$ is used to parametrize the circle.

Comment: (i) Some parentheses appear to have gotten lost: Should "$\alpha, \beta$" read "$(\alpha, \beta)$"? (ii) As written, $g$ is not obviously a mapping; it's necessary to show $g$ is well-defined. (iii) For injectivity, if $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ are real numbers such that $e^{i\alpha} = e^{i\alpha'}$, what can you say about $\alpha'$ in relation to $\alpha$?

Comment: @183orbco3 Thank you for the hint, I don’t have the picture in mind right now I will think of this !

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for your comment ! Yes a parenthesis was missing it’s corrected ! I did not think to check this yes . For $(iii)$ we will have $cos(\alpha)=cos(\alpha’)$ and $sin(\alpha)=sin(\alpha’)$ which can be satisfied only by $\alpha=\alpha’$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have some $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ and $(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$ such that $g(e^{i\alpha_1},e^{i\beta_1})=g(e^{i\alpha_2},e^{i\beta_2})$, and let $g_1,g_2,g_3$ denote the component functions of $g$.

By $$g_3(e^{i\alpha_1},e^{i\beta_1})=g_3(e^{i\alpha_2},e^{i\beta_2})$$

we get $\sin(\alpha_1)=\sin(\alpha_2)$, and by

$$[g_1(e^{i\alpha_1},e^{i\beta_1})]^2+[g_2(e^{i\alpha_1},e^{i\beta_1})]^2=[g_1(e^{i\alpha_2},e^{i\beta_2})]^2+[g_2(e^{i\alpha_2},e^{i\beta_2})]^2$$

we obtain $(a+r\cos(\alpha_1))^2=(a+r\cos(\alpha_2))^2$. As $0<r<a$ we have $a+r\cos(\alpha_1)>0$ and $a+r\cos(\alpha_2)>0$, and so $$a+r\cos(\alpha_1)=a+r\cos(\alpha_2)\implies \cos(\alpha_1)=\cos(\alpha_2)$$

As $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in [0,2\pi]$ and $\sin(\alpha_1)=\sin(\alpha_2), \space\cos(\alpha_1)=\cos(\alpha_2)$ we must have either $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ or one of the angles be $0$ and the other $2\pi$. In any case, $e^{i\alpha_1}=e^{i\alpha_2}$.

Dividing $g_1$ and $g_2$ by $a+r\cos(\alpha_1)=a+r\cos(\alpha_2)$ yields $$\cos(\beta_1)=\cos(\beta_2) \space\text{ and } \space\sin(\beta_1)=\sin(\beta_2)$$

A similar argument as before ensures $e^{i\beta_1}=e^{i\beta_2}$, from where the map is injective.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !